# Firebase Emulator request to Google Cloud Speech to Text Api denied

Tags: firebase, service-accounts, google-speech-to-text-api

I would like to test the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API from within Firebase Emulators. I currently have a trigger set on Firebase Storage that automatically gets fired when I upload a file via the Emulator Storage UI. This makes a request to the Speech to Text API, but I keep getting a permission denied error, as follows:

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Speech-to-Text API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I understand that project 563584335869 is the Firebase Cli project.
I have set the following environment variables when starting the emulator:

```
export GCLOUD_PROJECT=my-actual-glcloud-project-id && export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST='localhost:9099' && export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./path/to/service-account.json &&
firebase emulators:start
```

The service_account.json key file is associated with a service_account that has the following roles, as demonstrated by running

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy my_project_id --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:serviceAccount:my_service_account@my_project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/speech.admin
roles/storage.admin
roles/storage.objectAdmin
roles/storage.objectCreator
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

Since the credentials for the service account I am using should have admin access to the speech to text api, why do I keep getting a permission denied error when running from the emulator, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The project id 563584335869 is not yours. It is firebase-cli cloud project’s project-id. In this case, the problem is arising because you have to set your own configuration using your credentials or your key.

You can see below a code for NodeJS which I found in github[1] where it shows how to configure your authentication to use the API.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

// Create the auth config
const config = {
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
};

// Creates a client
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(config);
```

[1]https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-text-to-speech/issues/26

**EDIT**

There are different ways to set up your authentication for speech to text. One way to resolve this problem would be to add the same auth configuration as the Text-to-Speech and it should look something like this in your code.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Create the auth config
const authconfig = {
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
};

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient(authconfig);
```

Another way to solve this problem according to this Google Cloud Documentation[2] is to setup your authentication.

[2]https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication

Comment: Thanks for the link to Text-To-Speech documentation, but this question asks specifically about Google Speech to Text API. The sample config at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech#using-the-client-library offers no options to load a keyFilename.

Comment: @CambodianCoder I edited my answer let me know if this help you.